# Are there enough knots to cover $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Actually, several years ago I was in a short, introductory, course about knot theory, and my original question that I posed was: "can the knots be used to classify homeomorphims in $\mathbb{R}^3$?". What I was aiming at, concerned both to see about a proof if there were enough knots to cover the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and *if it is the case*, whether knots could be used as a sort of method to classify homeomorphisms.

Going deeper into knot theory, homeomorphisms are not enough to clearly distinguish among knots. Not even homotopies, one having to use actually ambient isotopies to really find mappings which would tell one knot from another; that is, if I understood the definitions correctly.

There are other definitions that I have found, but still I am not entirely sure on how to use them to answer my questions. Here they are, with their source:

"Classification theorem for closed surfaces 3.33: A closed, path-connected surface is homeomorphic to a 2-sphere, a connected sum of tori, or a connected sum of projective planes. The Euler characteristic and orientability of the surface distinguish among these possibilities" [Robert Messer, Philip Straffin, "Topology Now!, The Mathematical Association of America]

"Two smooth knots $K_0$ and $K_1$ are called *equivalent* if there exists a one-parameter family $f_t:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, r \in [0,1]$, of diffeomorphisms smoothly depending on the parameter $t$, taking the knot $K_0$ to the knot $K_1$, i.e., such that $f_0$ is the identity and $f_1(K_0) = K_1$. (Here 'smoothly' means that the map $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ given by $(x,t) \mapsto f_t(x)$ is differentiable.)The familiy of diffeomorphisms $f_t$ is said to be an *isotopy* joining the knots $K_0$ and $K_1$; for this reason equivalent knots are also called *isotopic* or *ambient isotopic*" [V. V. Prasolov, A. B. Sossinsky, "Knots, Links, Braid and 3-Manifolds. An Introduction to the New Invariants in Low-Dimensional Topology", American Mathematical Society]

"(2.1.1) Theorem. Two knots are ambient isotopic if and only if any diagram of one is equivalent to any diagram of the other under Reidemeister moves" [Dominic J. A. Welsh, "Complexity. Knots, Colourings and Counting", Cambridge University Press]

"Ambient isotopy is an equivalence relation on knots: two knots are equivalent if they can be deformed into one another. Each equivalence class of knots is called a *knot type*; equivalent knots have the same type." [Peter R. Cromwell, "Knots and Links", Cambridge University Press]

All the aforementioned statements say something about equivalence of knots (and suggest how to distinguish among them if there is a doubt), but, with the exception of the statement taken from Prasolov and Sossinsky, they do not really say much about its relationship with $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the questions that I posed, concerning the amount of coverage of knots of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the classification of at least some of its subsets.

Comment: Classify homeomorphisms of $\Bbb R^3$ up to what?

Comment: What do you mean, enough knots to cover $\mathbb{R}^3$? Of course there are knots landing at every point in $\mathbb{R}^3$, just by translating any unknot you like.

Comment: @Kevin Carlson, yes, I imagined that you could cover every point of $\mathbb(R^3)$ the way you described, but I wasn't sure if there could be "holes" of some kind. Do you think is there already written a formal way of expressing your answer? something like "for every point in $\mathbb(R^3)$, one can find a map of a closed surface..."

Comment: @PVAL I imagine it could be "classify homeomorphisms of $\R^3$ up to the  allowable, distinguishable types of knots", if one could express formally a classification along those lines.

Comment: @PVAL, I suppose one could state "up to a map of [certain given characteristics]" (which one should be able to estate formally what it is). Now, the problem (for me, at least) is precisely how one could phrase formally such a statement, and then prove it.

Comment: The formal way to express @KevinCarlson's comment is that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ there is a knot $K \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $x \in K$. To see this, start with any knot $K' \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and any point $x' \in K'$. Using vector arithmetic define  $K = \{x+y-x' \bigm| y \in K'\}$. This construction is so elementary that I see no hope of expecting any deep results to follow from it, such as classifying homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: since we can take as a given the covering of knots of the entire $\matbb(R)$, this already answers part of my question. The other part demands that I rephrase even the title, because now we must go to something that really distinguishes knots, namely ambient isotopies. For example "what are the characteristics and/or parameters that would distinguish one ambient isotopy to another, up to some kind of symmetry"; the idea being, if one can tell a knot from another through an isotopy, tell those aspects of the isotopy that may embed several types of knots, hence the homeomorphisms.